# How to remove a x quantity between several last rows?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I'm facing an issue concerning my willingness to remove a quantity to my last rows until this quantity goes to 0.

For instance, if my quantity to remove is 20, how can I remove it in my dataframe:

```
data.frame(Time = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), Quantity = c(5,9,2,17,23,101,15,21,7,3))
```

So, I have to subtract it to my last rows, to obtain:

```
data.frame(Time = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), Quantity = c(5,9,2,17,23,101,15,11))
```

Should I try a while loop?

Comment: Do you want to remove rows after your last entry which is greater than 20? `df[1:max(which(df$Quantity > 20)), ]` ?

Comment: My idea is more to remove each quantity (20 could be 10 then 2 then 7...) I will give and thus remove this quantity to the last raws (order by time) to remove the oldest

Comment: According to your question, you should have 11 at the end and not 21. Why do you have 21 then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using base R you could do something like:

```
del_val = function(val){
  a = cumsum(rev(df$Quantity))
  b = which(a>val)[1]
  replace(head(df,-b+1),cbind(nrow(df)-b+1,2),a[b]-val)
}
del_val(20)
  Time Quantity
1    1        5
2    2        9
3    3        2
4    4       17
5    5       23
6    6      101
7    7       15
8    8       11



del_val(9)
  Time Quantity
1    1        5
2    2        9
3    3        2
4    4       17
5    5       23
6    6      101
7    7       15
8    8       21
9    9        1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, as intuitive as it is I didn't know the `rev` function, I would think more about the `cumsum` in the future ! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

We can write a function to remove rows

```
return_rows  <- function(df, n) {
      vals <- cumsum(rev(df$Quantity))
      inds <- nrow(df) - max(which(vals < n))
      df$Quantity[inds] <- df$Quantity[inds] - (n - vals[nrow(df) - inds])
      df[seq_len(inds), ]
}

return_rows(df,20)

#  Time Quantity
#1    1        5
#2    2        9
#3    3        2
#4    4       17
#5    5       23
#6    6      101
#7    7       15
#8    8       11

return_rows(df,40)
#  Time Quantity
#1    1        5
#2    2        9
#3    3        2
#4    4       17
#5    5       23
#6    6      101
#7    7        6
```

Comment: did you just edit the question to have 21 at the end instead of 11?

Comment: @Onyambu yes, I thought that was a mistake from OP's side. Did I misunderstood the question?  Let me just roll back then.

Comment: @RonakShah, Yeah my idea was to drop a quantity X, for instance 20, distributed among the last rows of the dataframe ordered by `df$Time`

Comment: @AlexGermain sorry, I completely misunderstood the question initially. I have corrected it now.

Comment: Thank you both, I had trouble communicating my problem, thank you anyway

Comment: Just adding that the both solutions only works for a retired value greater than the Quantity presents on the last rows.